# графика 3d движка

Tags: java, графика, 3d

Для закрепления информации по паттернам ООП, решил написать простенький 3d кубач. Поиски способа преобразовать прямоугольник в трапецию, для создания эффекта перспективы, привели меня к решениям от oracle. Но их документация оставляет желать лучшего. Можно пример такого преобразования? 3d от javaFX думаю не использовать. Ведь не зная как работает вселенная, я не смогу приготовить пирог)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во время уточнения информации для вопроса, нашёл обновлённый сайт oracle, где всё понятно объяснено.

```
// свойство элемента к которому оно будет применено
        PerspectiveTransform perspectiveTrasform = new PerspectiveTransform();
        perspectiveTrasform.setUlx(10.0);// верхний левый угол по X
        perspectiveTrasform.setUly(10.0);// верхний левый угол по Y
        perspectiveTrasform.setUrx(310.0);// верхний правый угол по X
        perspectiveTrasform.setUry(40.0);// верхний правый угол по Y
        perspectiveTrasform.setLrx(310.0);// нижний правый угол по X
        perspectiveTrasform.setLry(60.0);// нижний правый угол по Y
        perspectiveTrasform.setLlx(10.0);// нижний левый угол по X
        perspectiveTrasform.setLly(90.0);// нижний левый угол по Y
        
        //выше был описан четырёхуголиник с определённой формой

        //просто фигуры
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.setX(10.0);
        rect.setY(10.0);
        rect.setWidth(280.0);
        rect.setHeight(80.0);
        rect.setFill(Color.web("0x3b596d"));


        Text text = new Text();
        text.setX(20.0);
        text.setY(65.0);
        text.setText("Perspective");
        text.setFill(Color.ALICEBLUE);
        text.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 36));


        // добавляем фигуры на форму 
        Group g = new Group(rect, text);
        
        // добавляем эффект на форму
        g.setEffect(perspectiveTrasform);
        
        g.setCache(true);
        Scene mainScene = new Scene(g);
        stage.setScene(mainScene);
        stage.show();
```

Чтоб понять что к чему, лучше самим попробовать поиграть с этим кодом.

Важно!!! решение только для javaFX